# Query not executed Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, sql

My sql query is giving the following error. The same query is running fine in other server.
Error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php:59 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php(59): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php on line 59 (Line 59 is $query->execute();)

```
             $expFormat = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") + 1, date("Y"));
             $expDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expFormat);
             $key = md5(time());
             $addKey = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), 1)), 3, 10);
             $key = $key . $addKey;
                $sql="INSERT INTO `password_reset_temp` (`email`, `key`, `expDate`) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $key . "', '" . $expDate . "');";
                $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
                $query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':key',$key,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->bindParam(':expDate',$expDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
```

[image: Table structure is click here]

Comment: Don't concatenate the variables' values but put the placeholders instead.

Comment: @stickybit can u explain  please

Comment: Well, I already explained... Don't concatenate the variables like `$email` and so on but put the placeholders like `:email` and so on into the query. And remove the quotes (`'`)  when you did so. The right quotes will be set automatically when the variables are bound to the query. (Maybe also have a look at an example in a tutorial or the documentation again and carefully see how they use the placeholders in their queries.

Comment: @stickybit my query is  now  $sql="INSERT INTO password_reset_temp(email,key,expDate) VALUES(:email,:key,:expDate)";

Comment: @stickybit it gives the error   - Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,expDate) VALUES('xxxxxxx@xxxx.org','8f46cc337bb661a650397f613266...' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php:60 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php(60): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sms\send_link.php on line 60

Comment: @stickybit Thnks

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't concatenate the variables' values but put the placeholders instead.
2. Key is a keyword in the mysql avoid using this try the following code .

```
$expFormat = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") + 1, date("Y"));
$expDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $expFormat);
$key = md5(time());
$addKey = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), 1)), 3, 10);
$key1 = $key . $addKey;
$sql="INSERT INTO password_reset_temp(email,key1,expDate) VALUES(:email,:key1,:expDate)";    
$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':key1',$key1,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':expDate',$expDate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```