# Error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in.. (path)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Iam getting values from HTML inputs and using ajax to send data from javascript to php and validate them with mysql but i get this error:

```
<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\\Program Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\pruebaLogin\\ajax\\procesar_registro.php:12\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\Program Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\pruebaLogin\\ajax\\procesar_registro.php(12): PDOStatement-&gt;execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in <b>C:\\Program Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\pruebaLogin\\ajax\\procesar_registro.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />\n"
```

I notice on status is: 200 so i think the problem is maybe inside php file. I'm not sure, I am new with php.

Javascript:

```
$(document).on("submit", ".form_registro", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
   
    var data_form = {
        nickname: $("#nickname",$form).val(),
        password: $("#password", $form).val() 
    }
    if(data_form.nickname.length < 4 ){
        $("#msg_error").text("Tu usuario no puede ser menor a 4 letras").show();
        return false;        
    }else if(data_form.password.length < 5){
        $("#msg_error").text("Tu password debe ser minimo de 8 caracteres.").show();
        return false;   
    }
    $("#msg_error").hide();
    var url_php = 'http://localhost:8077/pruebalogin/ajax/procesar_registro.php';

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: url_php,
        data: data_form,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
    })
    .done(function ajaxDone(res){
       console.log(res); 
        if(res.error !== undefined){
            $("#msg_error").text(res.error).show();
            return false;
       } 

       if(res.redirect !== undefined){
        window.location = res.redirect;
    } 
    })
    .fail(function ajaxError(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
    .always(function ajaxSiempre(){
        console.log('Final de la llamada ajax.');
    })
    return false;
});
```

I have this php file to check if user exists and create a new one if not

```
<?php
require_once "../inc/config.php";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    $return_array=[];
    $nickname = strtolower($_POST['nickname']);

     /* Checking if user exists */
    $find_user = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nickname = '$nickname' LIMIT 1");
    $find_user->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $find_user->execute();

        /* if exists */
    if($find_user->rowCount() == 1){
        $return_array['error'] = "Este usuario ya está registrado";
        $return_array['is_login']= false;
    }else{
        $password =password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
        $new_user = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nickname, password) VALUES(:nickname, :password)");
        $new_user->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $new_user->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $new_user->execute();

        $user_id = $con->lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION['user_id']= (int) $user_id;
        $return_array['redirect']= ''; 
        $return_array['is_login']= true;
    }

    echo json_encode($return_array);

}else{
    exit("Refused");
}


?>
```

Comment: In your first query, you're binding to a parameter `:nickname` that does not exist in your query. You've already dropped the variable `$nickname` straight into the query without using a parameter. That's what's causing the error: thanks to `bindParam()` you have 1 bound parameter but your query contains `0` tokens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query not executed Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964238/query-not-executed-uncaught-pdoexception-sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-num)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
 $find_user = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nickname = '$nickname' LIMIT 1");
    $find_user->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Should read

```
 $find_user = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nickname = :nickname LIMIT 1");
    $find_user->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

When you're using bindParam, you don't put the data into the prepare statement you put the place holder, which in this case is `:nickname`